# DNS resolve without depending on router for asterisk system

Tags: dns, asterisk, dhcp, zeroconf, resolve

Basically I have a Debian box running asterisk assigned an IP via DHCP with host-name XXX. My windows browser can resolve the host-name but if I use host-name in X-Lite or my SPA922 phone it fails to resolve. Is there any way of getting this to work without depending on the router or assigning a static IP (request is to make it portable). I was thinking zero-conf but am unsure (box has limited HDD too). Any help is most appreciated.

Comment: Try asking on http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you could do this.

Personally I replaced my stock router firmware with DD-WRT and it then serves as both the DHCP server and supports a local name server (so all machines on the local LAN can access each other by name).

Not quite "not depending on the router" but pretty low configuration, and nothing to configure at all on the client devices really.